# Mac ローカルにインストールされている PostgreSQL/9.4 をアンインストールしたい。

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

### 前提・実現したいこと

Homebrew でインストールしました、 Mac ローカルの PostgreSQL/9.4 をアンインストールしたいのですが、どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

1. PostgreSQL 9.4 をアンインストールしたい。
2. その後、PostgreSQL 9.5をインストールしたい。

---

### 試したこと

`brew uninstall postgresql` コマンドを実行しても PostgreSQL/9.4 がアンインストールされません。

```sh
$ ps aux | grep post

postgres            84   0.0  0.0  2622976    352   ??  Ss    8 816    0:09.91 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/data
```

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

- Mac OS X バージョン 10.9.5

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

---

### 追記

```sh
$ ls /Library/PostgreSQL/
9.4
```

と表示されました。

```sh
$ brew list
autoconf    git     openssl     pkg-config  rbenv       readline    ruby-build

$ psql -l
-bash: /usr/local/bin/psql: No such file or directory

$ exec bash
bash-3.2

bash-3.2$ psql -l
bash: psql: command not found
```

Comment: 「brew list」の実行結果、追記しました。仰る通り表示されませんでした。現状は「psql -l」を実行しても、本文に記載されているエラー文が表示されてしまいPostgresqlに接続することができません。なぜ接続できないのかアドバイス頂けたら幸いです。宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: それは、`bash`が昔の`psql`コマンドのありかを覚えている（キャッシュしている）からです。`exec bash`とかで再起動すれば、また$PATHの中から`psql`を探しますから、今残っている方が見つかると思いますよ。

Comment: ありがとうございます！「exec bash」実行しました。実行結果を本文に追記させて頂きました。知識不足で申し訳ありませんが、この状態から抜けるにはどうすれば良いのでしょか？ また「exec bash」実行後、「psql -l」を実行しましたが、本文のエラーが発生しました。

Comment: 「この状態」とはプロンプトが変わっている事でしょうか。これはなんでしょうね。元からbashを使っていれば変わらない気がするのですが……まあ気になるようであれば端末ごと再起動でよいです。`psql`が見つからないのは、元のPostgreSQLにはパスを通していなかったようですね。`/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql `あたりにあるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: （コメントが長くなってもよくないので、本文に反映された分は削除していきます）

Comment: PATH の追加等をしたときの再検索は `csh` `tcsh` の場合は `rehash` コマンドを使い `bash` の場合は `hash -r` コマンドを使うといいでしょう。